# How I match an HTML attribute using Notepad++ regular expression search?

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

Here is my text:

```
<span class="c1">Testing "this string"</span>
```

and I want to end up with this:

```
<span>Testing "this string"</span>
```

so I tried to use this regex in Notepad++ to replace with nothing:

```
 class=".*"
```

but that matches this:

```
 class="c1">Testing "this string"
```

How do I stop that match after one instance of "?

Comment: where are you doing this? on server using server-side code or in the browser?

Comment: @Scott: OP is asking how to replace it using Notepad++. I've tagged and edited the title accordingly.

Comment: This summarizes my feelings about HTML and regex very well :-) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Scott - Cleaning up a client's frontpage code using HTML Tidy to clean and convert <font> to classes, then removing the classes in Notepad++.

Comment: @Franci that's my go-to link for this sort of questions usually too, but in this case the OP wants to do find and replace within their IDE, so it's a legitimate exception ;)

Comment: @Daniel: Notepad++ isn't an IDE, but it **does** beat up a lot of IDEs when it comes to code editing in general <3

Comment: @BoltClock potato, potato (I guess that doesn't really work in text). :)

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis - yeah, I just couldn't help myself... :-)

Comment: @Daniel: pardon my sheer ignorance. Care to explain what that means?

Comment: @BoltClock you know the old song "you say potato (pronounced po-tay-to) I say potato (poh-tah-to)"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, regular expressions are [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) (and so `.*` will match **as much** as it possibly can, which, in your case is `c1">Testing "this string`). In general, you have two ways of getting around this:

1. Use a [nongreedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) (or lazy) modifier (`.*?`), which will match as little as possible (in your case, just `c1`). Notepad++ doesn't support lazy modifiers, though.
2. Specify exactly what you want to match with `class="[^"]*"`, which will match everything that isn't a quote. In general, this is the more optimized solution, as well.

Comment: +1 for the complementary character class. (I'll do it once my vote limit resets though.)

Comment: Notepad++ didn't work with the ?, but the second solution was perfect. Thanks!!

Comment: @Khan: as BoltClock mentioned below, Notepad++ doesn't support ungreedy modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

```
class=".*?"
```

Will make the `*` [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).