# Can I Find and Replace html links using Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I want to find and replace a bunch of links, except I don't know how to format the search expression. I want to find the links that look like this:

```
http://website.com/test.php?id=930&name=hello
```

The 930 and hello are the variables that are different.

edit: I tried `"http://website.com/test.php?id=.*&name=.*">` but it selects a bunch of stuff after that too like img src on that line etc

I tried using `[^"]`* or `(.*?)` instead of `.*` but it says it can't find the text :(

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587956/how-i-match-an-html-attribute-using-notepad-regular-expression-search

Comment: I tried following it in the link you gave me, but it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ seems to have limited regex. It doesn't use the nongreedy variants (`.*?`) and some anchors for word boundaries like `\b`, `\Z` are also not working.

I think this will help you:

```
http://website.com/test.php?id=\d*&name=\w*
```

insted of searching for `.*` which will also match to whitespaces, use `\d*` this will find only numbers and `\w*`, this will find only letters.

If the name can contain other things than letters than use this

```
http://website.com/test.php?id=\d*&name=[\w\d]*
```

and add into the `[]` all you need to match. in my example it will match letters and numbers.

Hint for future questions: Think about your tags. If you would have used the tag "regex", you would have gotten 5 answers within minutes for your question.